# set bootbox dialog window focus through select2-open event

Tags: jquery-select2, bootbox

I am opening a bootbox dialog box when the user click inside select-2 input box using the following code

```
$("#categoryfinder").on("select2-open", function () {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
        Example.show("Confirm result: " + result);
    });
});
```

Once it is opened, the popup window is not active and I have to click twice to close or to trigger any event on the popup

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

EDIT: when I click inside 1, the popup is not active at 1,2,3, I have to click once to make it active.

[image]

Comment: Do you want it so the Select2 drop-down does not open if the user chooses "Cancel" and does open if the user chooses "OK"?

Comment: I am not opening the select2 dropdown.I have "dropdownCssClass: 'noshow'," in the config.when you tab in select2 control, it is opening a popup and it is not active

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by doing the following changes

```
$("#allergenfinder").on("select2-opening", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    excludeAllergenPrompt();

});
```